# How to use RestAPI in xamarin for Visual Studio

Tags: android, rest, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I want display or modify SQL data through app. I am using xamarin for Visual studio and currently creating app for android. I have created Web API(Rest) which has three methods . One method retrieves data , second method verify data and third method add data in to the database.

Basically I created this API so that I can use it across multiple platform. I need some hep for android app how to consume that rest API and call particular method based on click event of Button.

If there is any other way through which I can securely use SQL database using Xamarin for visual studio .
Any any tutorial, example or link will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the Xamarin website:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

There is a tutorial here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfoJCd_TMx0

There are some Xamarin components which may help too, e.g:
https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp/

Hope that helps